# How to use ngModel directive's formatter/parsers in a custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to use `ng-model` formatters/parsers in my directive. The problem is that the formatter is not working as expected it correctly returns the result but it's not applied in the input box. (see console logs in the demo).

If I run the directive directly on the input tag with-out my directive template it works as expected. I can't see what's the problem.
It could be a scoping issue but I'm not sure. How can I fix this?

### How does the directive work

The directive stores an HTML entity in the model (e.g. `&copy;`) and displays in the text input field as copyright symbol (©). Later, I'll add the symbols with buttons to the text field. It's not a real app for me just for learning Angular.

Below is the demo of my code or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/pj32dsqv/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngSanitize'])
 .controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myModel = '&copy;&reg;';
 })
 .directive('myInput', function($timeout, $sanitize, $sce, $parse) {
 return {
     restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
         inputText: '=ngModel'
        },
        template: '<div>some other html here... <input ng-model="inputText"/></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            
            /*scope.$watch('inputText', function() {
               scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel + ' = inputText');
            });

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(val) {
                scope.inputText = val;
            });*/
            
            /*scope.$watch('ngModel', function() {
             scope.inputText = scope.ngModel;
            });*/
            console.log(element);
            
            /*ngModel.$render = function() {
              element.html('click me!! counter: ' + ngModel.$viewValue);
            };*/
            
            //format text going to user (model to view)
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
                
                var decoded = angular.element('<div/>').html($sce.trustAsHtml(value)).text();
                console.log('formatter', value, decoded, $sce.trustAsHtml(value)); //, $parse(value));
                return decoded;//$sce.getTrustedHtml(value);
            });
            
            //format text from the user (view to model)
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                console.log('parser', value, $sanitize(value));
                return $sanitize(value); ///\d+/.exec(value)[0]); ///\d+/.exec(value)[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    model value = {{myModel}}<br/>
    <my-input ng-model="myModel"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a work-around. As mentioned in the comments with another directive it is working because then `ngModel` can directly work on the input element and I think it's OK to have another directive to make it work. Also the parser (view to model) is working now.

I'm still not sure why my previous code fails. But I could figure out the following:

The formatter is running twice if the `ng-model` directive is inside of the template. First with the correctly formatted symbols (©®) and at the second run it sets the view value to `&copy;&reg;`. And that gets added to the input field.
Seems like the parser of the `ngModel` of the directive at the input tag gets called and sanitize the symbols but I'm not sure.

If someone has an idea how to fix it with-out another directive please let me know.

So have a look at the working code below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/pj32dsqv/9/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myModel = '&copy;&reg;';
})
    .directive('encodeEntity', function ($sanitize, $sce) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            /*ngModel.$render = function () {
                //console.log(ngModel.$viewValue);
                console.log('rendered');
                element.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };*/

            function decode(value) {
             return angular.element('<div/>')
                    .html($sce.trustAsHtml(value || '')).text();
            }
            //format text going to user (model to view)
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                var decoded = decode(value);
                console.log('formatter', value, decoded);
                return decoded;
            });

            //format text from the user (view to model)
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                console.log('parser', value, $sanitize(value));
                var newModelValue = $sanitize(value),
                    inputStr = '' + value,
                    startPos = inputStr.indexOf('&'),
                    last = inputStr.length - 1;
                
                if ( startPos !== -1 && inputStr[last] == ';') { 
                    console.log('update symbol');
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(decode(newModelValue));
                    ngModel.$render();
                }
                
                return newModelValue;
            });
        }
    }
})
    .directive('myInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            inputText: '=ngModel'
        },
        //terminal: true, // terminal true deactivates any directives that are running at lower priority, e.g. an ng-model directive inside of the template
        template: '<div>Template:<input ng-model="inputText" encode-entity/></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            /* do stuff of main directiv here.... */

        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">model value = {{myModel}}
    <br/>
    <my-input ng-model="myModel" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is angularjs will encode everything that you want to display. If you want to display html, you can change the code like:

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    model value = <span ng-bind-html="myModel"></span><br/>
    <my-input ng-model="myModel"/>
</div>
```

`ng-bind-html` expects an object returned by: `$sce.trustAsHtml`.

So in your formatter just:

```
return $sce.getTrustedHtml(value);
```

(not sure why it was commented out)

Comment: It's commented because I think I can not use `ng-bind-html` on an input. Please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/pj32dsqv/4/) than it's more clear how it should work. There the formatting is working as expected, just parsing needs to be improved. I just removed the template and added my directive as attribute to the input. The `{{myModel}}` is just to show the `$modelValue`. So how to get it working with the template? I've thought I could add the model formatter in another directive and add it inside of the template. But that seems too complicated.